# Observable: switch if less than X items emitted

Tags: mongodb, rx-java, rx-scala

I have a list of observables obs1, obs2, obs3,...,

Each of them can emit a number of items (from mongodb database), I am interested only in the first N items. I want to make sure that queries of my observables are executed only if required. In other words, if obs1, for example, produce more than N, the query behind obs2 should not run, etc.

If I use concat: Observable(obs1, obs2, obs3, ...).concat, all of the queries can run in parallel in mongodb

Basically, I am looking for an operation like obs1.switchIfX(obs2).switchIfX(obs3).....

Where X: less than N items are emitted by current observable.

Any idea how I can implement this requirement in rxscala style?

Comment: If N is 10 and `obs1` produced 5, should that 5 be made available to the downstream or should it be ignored and `obs2` subscribed to?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
Observable.just(obs1, obs2, obs3).flatten(maxConcurrent=1).take(N)
```

The `maxConcurrent` argument ensures that `flatten` only subscribes to one observable at a time, and once `N` items have been emitted, `take` will unsubscribe from the upstream observable, so if at that point, `obs2` or `obs3` have not yet been subscribed to, they will never be run, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the items from the source into a list, check its size in a `flatMap` operator and switch to another source if the length is not enough:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.range(1, 5)
    .compose(switchIfFewer(Observable.range(1, 8), 10))
    .compose(switchIfFewer(Observable.range(1, 15), 10))
    .test()
    .assertResult(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
}

static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> switchIfFewer(Observable<T> other, int n) {
    return o -> {
        return o.toList()
        .flatMapObservable(list -> {
            if (list.size() < n) {
                return other;
            }
            return Observable.fromIterable(list);
        });
    };
}
```

If you don't want to get more than N items, you can specify `o.take(n).toList()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very, it is very helpful but what I want is the first N from obs1, obs2, obs3 in this order. This means in your example, I am expecting 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5, basically only obs1 and obs2 emits and obs3 not

Comment: I don't understand. You want the first N elements from each source? That's like `just(obs1, obs2, obs3).concatMap(o -> o.take(N))`.

Comment: No, N elements in total. Suppose N=5, obs1 emit 2, obs2 emit 4, then I will take the 2 elements from obs1,  3 from obs2 and ignore obs3 since I have already collected 5.